# Azure Servicebus REST API : How to retrieve MessageId

Tags: azure, servicebus

I want to use REST API to send message to a servicebus topic.
Everything's working fine, the message is sent on the topic.
My client received an ACK fron servicebus by receiving an HTTP code 201, a void body, and some headers.
But I didn't received the messageId. I need it to retrieve treatment status in my internal product.

However, as at described into the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/message-headers-and-properties), the MessageId should be returned.

Is it normal? And how can I retrieve the MessageId?

The only other option is to set the MessageId by the client way, but I don't like this solution because it is not the responsability of the client to do that.

Comment: If more information about the API link and screenshot will be better.

Comment: Here the API documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/service-bus-runtime-rest  I don't see what  screenshots you need : Azure ServiceBus? There are too many screen... My postman to send requests?

Comment: Apparently, the message producer need to set the message id if needed.